# Scheduled tasks set to "run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" don't work?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm creating tasks in Windows Server 2016 using PowerShell. I want the tasks to run once. I need the tasks to be bullet proof so that if the server happens to be down at the scheduled run time, it will run when the server comes back. I've checked the "run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" option. The tasks are run once. Code below. For the life of me I can't get the tasks to run if they miss their start time.

Any ideas?

```
$TicketRef = "1234"
$UsrLeaver = "michael dawson"
$UsrInheritor = "richard hall"
$LeaveDateTime = ""
$GracePeriod = 30
$OooMessage = "Goodbye"

####################################
###### Setup Off-Boarding Job ######
####################################

# Calculate proper Date and Times
$OffboardDateTime = Get-Date 
$LeaveDate = $OffboardDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$LeaveTime = $OffboardDateTime.ToString("HH:mm")

$ArgString = "& 'C:\Scripts\_UserScripting\Script\TestJob.ps1' 'Offboard' '$TicketRef' '$UsrLeaver' '$UsrInheritor' '$LeaveDate' '$LeaveTime' '$OooMessage'"

# Set up action to run
$STAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
-Execute 'Powershell.exe' `
-Argument $ArgString

# Set up trigger to launch action
$STTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger `
-Once `
-At ([DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(1))

# Set up base task settings - NOTE: Win8 is used for Windows 10
$STSettings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet `
-Compatibility Win8 `
-MultipleInstances IgnoreNew `
-StartWhenAvailable

# Name of Scheduled Task
$DateTime = $OffboardDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm")
$STName = "$DateTime - Off-Board - $UsrLeaver"
$STFolder = 'Off-Boarding'

# Create Scheduled Task
Register-ScheduledTask `
-Action $STAction `
-Trigger $STTrigger `
-Settings $STSettings `
-TaskName $STName `
-TaskPath $STFolder `
-Description "Scheduled User Off-Boarding" `
-User "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" `
-RunLevel Highest


# Get the Scheduled Task data and make some tweaks
$TargetTask = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $STName

# Set desired tweaks
$TargetTask.Author = 'IT Support'
$TargetTask.Triggers[0].StartBoundary = [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
$TargetTask.Triggers[0].EndBoundary = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
$TargetTask.Settings.AllowHardTerminate = $True
$TargetTask.Settings.DeleteExpiredTaskAfter = 'PT1M'
$TargetTask.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = 'PT1H'
$TargetTask.Settings.volatile = $False

# Save tweaks to the Scheduled Task
$TargetTask | Set-ScheduledTask
```

Answer (score 0):

"run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" option.
I tried every possible method in  windows task scheduler to run a missed task but all efforts failed.
If the task scheduler is set to run after a particular set time it works , but if the task say for example was supposed to run yesterday is missed for some reason , this task doesn't run.
There is some issue with windows task scheduler for dates older than current date. For some reason even "I can't get the tasks to run if they miss their start time."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Need to raise a ticket or ask Microsoft support.